# Antiminer s3 won't show the correct interface once i connect to (showing a DLink interface instead)

Tags: miner-configuration, antminer

Recently, I bought an Antminer s3 from eBay and I am having an issue with it. I am able to connect the miner to the internet just fine as its showing up on my router. However, it doesn't show the usual antminer interface, instead it shows a dlink interface with only network connection settings. It does not even show the pool settings. Can anyone here assist me? I spoke with the seller but I am not getting anywhere on that front.